# In C++, Can't I implement this classes without separating header and cpp?

Tags: c++, class

Suppose I have "A.hpp", "B.hpp", and "main.cpp".

#### A.hpp

```
#ifndef _A_HPP_
#define _A_HPP_

#include "B.hpp"

class A {
public:
  B& b_;

  A(B& b) : b_(b) {
  }

  void foo() {
     b_.foo();
  }
};

#endif
```

#### B.hpp

```
#ifndef _B_HPP_
#define _B_HPP_

#include "A.hpp"

class B {
public:
  A* a_;
  B() : {
    a_ = new A( *this );
  }

  void foo() {
  }
};

#endif
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"
#include "A.hpp"

int main()
{
   B b;
   b.a->foo();
   return 0;
}
```

I know why I can't compile main.cpp but don't know how can I fix this situation without seperating header file and source file for classes A and B. ( For example situation , classes A and B are using template )

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: why do you want not to seperate? seperation seems needed in your case.

Comment: Sure you can do anything without header file, just put everything in single file. Since this is what `#include` do for you.

Comment: @appleapple There's a circular reference in `A`-to-`B`, there are include guards so the compiler will complaint that `A.hpp` (included via `B.hpp` via `main.cpp`) is referencing undefined symbol `B`.)

Comment: @Dai Yes I missed that, anyway, separating *file* or not is not relevant.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_A_CPP_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - you want to be able to compile `main.cpp` without needing separate translation units for `A` and `B`, and without having to seprate-out `A` and `B`'s interface and implementation?

You can do this - but you will still need to follow the rules for forward-declaration:

```
class B; // class `B` forward-declaration

// define class A, but don't implement the parts that need B's definition

class A {
public:
    B& b_; // `A` can use `B` here, but the compiler still doesn't know how B is defined

    A(B&& b); // also need to define A's structure, but not the method implementations
    void foo(); 
};

class B {
public:
    A* a_;
    B() : {
        a_ = new A( *this );
    }
    void foo() { }
};

// now we can define `A` using the `A::` syntax, instead of class{}:
A::A(B&& b) : b_(b) { }
void A::foo() { b_.foo(); }

int main()
{
   B b;
   b.a->foo();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the declarations of `A`'s methods inside its `class` block.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thank you - I forgot about that

Comment: Also, if you want that stuff to be in a header, they need to be marked explicitly as `inline`, otherwise you'll get multiple definition errors when linking.

Comment: @Matteo indeed. Note that if the member function definitions are inside the class definition, they are implicitly inline. So inline is only needed when the member function definition is placed outside the class definition as is the case in this answer.